# How to force multiple clients to leave in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm working on a script where the logic states that if the person who has created a room via the socket.io 'create room' method, something along the lines of:

```
client.on("createRoom", function (name) {
    client.room = name;
    client.join(client.room);
    client.emit("update", "Welcome to room:" + name + ".");
});
```

Multiple people can join the same room via another method. My question is, how to implement a solution where - if the owner of the room (a unique ID produced by socket.io is stored in my script and noted as the 'owner') disconnects from the server, all other connected client that belong to the same room also disconnect? I know I have to use the client.leave() method but I'm not sure how I can apply that to multiple clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the clients in an array, as objects. Store the room number and if they own the room in the properties. On the disconnect event, check the `ownsroom` property of the user in question, and if so, loop through the array searching for other clients where the `roomid` property matches that of the disconnecting owners. When the if statement for `clients[i].roomid == disconnected.roomid` is true, call the leave function to drop the connection.

```
var i = 0;
while(i < clients.length){
    if(clients[i].room == disconnected.room)
        clients[i].leave();
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. By 'room number' do you mean the ID of the room? also, are you saying to do clients[i].leave()? I'm not sure if I follow the last part of your explanation.

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to rework this to my needs. I have a people object that contains all the connected clients and whether a person owns a room or is in a room and it's keyed on the client.id: people[client.id] = {"name" : name, "owns" : ownerRoomID, "inroom" : inRoomID};

Comment: one more question. var clients = []; and on the socket join method -> clients.push(client.id); doesn't seem sufficient. how to store clients in an array as objects?

Comment: You have to push client, not client.id